# RegExp in javascript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

here is my element:

```
<div id="main_keyword" data-type="meta" contenteditable="true" minlength="0" maxlength="10" paste_as_text="true" class="h-10 w-full p-2 bg-white overflow-y-auto shadow dark:bg-front-dark-2 dark:text-white" style="margin-left: 1.6rem;">hiking&nbsp;<mark style="color:#219B38;background:none;font-weight:500;"><mark style="color:#219B38;background:none;font-weight:500;">joffre lake</mark>s</mark></div>
```

text content result:

```
document.getElementById("main_keyword").textContent
output===> "hiking joffre lakes"
```

I am trying to get match as following, first is ok but getting error in second match.

match:

```
document.getElementById("main_keyword").textContent.match(new RegExp("joffre lakes", "ig"))
result===> ["joffre lakes"]
```

PROBLEM IS HERE:

expected result is `"hiking joffre lakes"` but I'm getting as:

```
document.getElementById("main_keyword").textContent.match(new RegExp("hiking joffre lakes", "ig"))
result===> null
```

I don't know why

Comment: i'ts probably the `&nbsp;` - try `new RegExp("hiking\\sjoffre\\slakes", "ig"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some unwanted white spaces to the `textContent`. Sanitize them a.k.a replace multiple spaces by single space and match again.

```js
let content = document.getElementById("main_keyword").textContent;
content = content.replace(/\s+/, ' ');
const matches = content.match(new RegExp('hiking joffre lakes', 'ig'));
console.log({matches});
```

```html
<div id="main_keyword" data-type="meta" contenteditable="true" minlength="0" maxlength="10" paste_as_text="true" class="h-10 w-full p-2 bg-white overflow-y-auto shadow dark:bg-front-dark-2 dark:text-white" style="margin-left: 1.6rem;">hiking&nbsp;<mark style="color:#219B38;background:none;font-weight:500;"><mark style="color:#219B38;background:none;font-weight:500;">joffre lake</mark>s</mark></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I replaced the additional spaces with single space and it worked.

Comment: You can do it also `let content = document.getElementById("main_keyword").textContent.replace(/\s+/, ' ')` (In one line).

Comment: Yes, actually used this way:
`document.getElementById("main_keyword").textContent.replace(/\s+/, ' ').match(new RegExp("hiking joffre lakes", "ig"))`